# New Office365 emails and passwords don't authenticate to create an appointment in Exchange

Tags: c#, authentication, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

At first I thought this was a Net5 coding problem since I upgraded my C# code from Net4.  We recently got a different subscription for Office365 with new company emails.  Our old emails and passwords still work fine with the following code but the new Office365 emails get a 401 unauthorized error kicked back. I have even run the new Office365 emails thru our old Net4 code and get the same result.  I am thinking this is an Exchange setting on the server side.  Hope someone has some answers as this code has been running fine for 7 years. Here is the code:

```
    private void CreateAppointment()
    {
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            //Setup Exchange;
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

            #region Authentication

            // Set specific credentials.
            service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            // Credentials for selected shared calendar is selected estimator
            //
            service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SelectedEstimator.Email, SelectedEstimator.OfficePassWord);
            service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            #endregion

            Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
            // Set the properties on the appointment object to create the appointment.
            appointment.Subject = Title;
            const string newLine = " <br /> ";
            body.Append("Email: " + EditCustomer.Email);
            body.Append(newLine);
            body.Append(EditCustomer.Notes);

            appointment.Body = body.ToString();
            appointment.Start = AppointmentDate;
            _appointmentStart = AppointmentDate.ToString();
            appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(1);
            _appointmentEnd = appointment.End.ToString();
            appointment.Location = Location;
            appointment.IsReminderSet = false;


            //appointment.ReminderDueBy = DateTime.Now;

            // Save the appointment to your calendar.
            appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
            // The save throws the 401 unauthorized error

            // Verify that the appointment was created by using the appointment's item ID.
            Item item = Item.Bind(service, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject));
            if (item.Subject == appointment.Subject)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Appointment Created!!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 no longer supports Basic authentication - it must be explicitly enabled by the admin. All new mailboxes require OAuth.